# Java - Only Two Rounded Corners on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rounded-corners

I would like to round the top two corners on a JFrame for a project I am currently working on. I am currently rounding all four corners using `setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 252, 30, 30));` but I do not want the bottom two rounded I want the to be a normal corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can combine shapes to get this.By combining roundered rectangle with a normal rectangle you can make a rectangle without bottom two rounded corners.

for example

```
public class example extends JFrame{

    public example() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

        Area shape1 = new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 252, 30, 30));
        Area shape2 = new Area(new Rectangle(0, 252-30, 200, 100));
        shape1.add(shape2);
        this.setShape(shape1);
        this.setSize(300, 400);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new example().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

alternatively you can give smaller height to the frame than RoundRectangle rectangle .so you can't see bottom  of the RoundRectangle .and then you can get desired output